# Sonarqube for compilation errors in PLSQL script

Tags: sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint, sonarqube-ops

is there a rule available in Sonarqube PlSql plugin, for finding compilation errors in the SQL script file that is being analyzed ?

example:
         select * table_name; -- from keyword misssing.
         or
         insert into table_name ('something','inserted','data'); -- values keyword missing.

Answer (score 1):

SonarQube Code Analyzers assume they're being passed compilable (or already-compiled) code. So no, no rule will be available for this.